# Resource plan for creation although count evaluates to false

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following variables

```
variable "policies" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of policy document to attach to the IAM Role."
  default     = []
}

variable "policy_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Name of the policy attached to the IAM Role."
  default     = null
}

variable "policy_description" {
  type        = string
  description = "Description of the policy attached to the IAM Role."
  default     = ""
}
```

Which are used by the following Terraform resources:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "this" {
  name               = var.role_name
  assume_role_policy = var.assume_role_policy
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  count                   = var.policies != [] ? 1 : 0
  source_policy_documents = var.policies
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "this" {
  count       = var.policies != [] ? 1 : 0
  name        = var.policy_name
  description = var.policy_description
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this[count.index].json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "this" {
  count      = var.policies != [] ? 1 : 0
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.this[count.index].arn
  role       = aws_iam_role.this.name
}
```

Now, my understanding is that `aws_iam_policy_document`, `aws_iam_policy` and `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` are to be created only when `var.policies` is not empty.

However, these resources are still plan for creation when calling them like

```
module "iam_role_batch" {
  source             = "./resources/iam/role"
  role_name          = local.iam_role_batch_service_name
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.batch_service.json
}
```

```
# module.iam_role_batch.aws_iam_policy.this[0] will be created
+ resource "aws_iam_policy" "this" {
    + arn       = (known after apply)
    + id        = (known after apply)
    + name      = (known after apply)
    + path      = "/"
    + policy    = jsonencode(
          {
            + Statement = null
            + Version   = "2012-10-17"
          }
      )
    + policy_id = (known after apply)
    + tags_all  = (known after apply)
  }

# module.iam_role_batch.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.this[0] will be created
+ resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "this" {
    + id         = (known after apply)
    + policy_arn = (known after apply)
    + role       = "xxxxxxx"
  }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Why? AFAIK, `policies` is by default set to `[]`, so the resources should not be planned for creation.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is by default set to []

Actually it is set to data type of `list(string)`. So your condition `var.policies != []` is always true, and that is why the resource is always created. `[]` is not the same as `list(string)`.

Usually you would do the following instead:

```
count       = length(var.policies) > 0 ? 1 : 0
```